# When using CI/CD in VSTS, should the publish step be part of the build or the "release"?

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I have a VSTS project and I'm setting up CI/CD at the moment. All fine, but I seem to have 2 options for the publishing step:

Option 1: it's a task as part of the CI Build, e.g. see build step 3 here:
https://medium.com/@flu.lund/setting-up-a-ci-pipeline-for-deploying-your-angular-application-to-azure-using-visual-studio-team-f686c8f190cf

Option 2: The build phase produces artifacts, and as part of a separate release phase these artifacts are published, see here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/ci-cd-part-1?view=vsts

Both options seem well supported in the MS documentation, is one of these options better than the other? Or is it a case of pros & cons for each and it depends on circumstances, etc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely use "Option 2".  Your build should not make changes in your environments whatsoever, that is strictly what a "release" is.  That link you have under "Option 1" is the wrong way to do it, a build should be just that, compiling code and making artifacts, not actually deploying code.

When you mesh build/releases together, you make it very difficult to debug build issues.  Since your code is always being released, you really have to disable the "deploy" step to get any idea of what was built before you deployed.

Also, the nice thing about creating an artifact is you have a deployable package, and if in the future you need to rollback to a previous working version, you have that ready to go.  Using the "build only" strategy, you'd have to revert your code or make unnecessary backups to achieve this.

I think you'll find any new Microsoft documentation pointing you toward this approach, and VSTS is completely set up like this.  Even the "Configure Continuous Delivery in Azure..." feature in Visual Studio 2017 will create a build and a release.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. I ended up going this route, though it's confusing that the build process allows for adhoc releases like this, I guess it could be useful for non-production quick deploys or something.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all build tasks are the same as release tasks, so you can deploy the app after building the project in build process.

Also there are many differences between release and build, for example, many environments, deployment group phase in release.

So which way is better is per to your detail requirement, for example, if build > deploy > other process is simple, you can do it just in build.

Regarding Publish artifact task, it is used to publish the files to VSTS server or other place (e.g. shared folder), which can be used in release as Artifact (Click Add artifact > Build in release definition), you also can download them for troubleshooting, for example, if you are using Hosted Agent that you can’t access, but you want to get some files (e.g. build result), you can add publish artifact task to publish to VSTS server, then download them (Open build result > Artifacts)